# Search for processes which are CPU consumming

Tags: command-line, awk, ps

I can track the process launched by the `user4` with `awk`:

```
ps aux | awk '$1~/user4/'
```

And also to track what process consume more than `10% CPU`:

```
ps aux | awk '$3> 10'
```

How can I combine both with `awk`, aka search for process launched by `user4` which are consumming more than `10% CPU`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok ... I found it reading more `awk` documentation, sorry for disturbing:

```
ps aux | awk '$1~/user4/ && $3> 0'
```

Comment: since ~ is pattern-matching, be careful if you ever end up with a "user44" or "ruser4"

Comment: this is completely true! I went for '$1~/user4$/ && $3> 0' to avoid this

Comment: Consider == as well

Answer (score 1):

or as an alternative

```
ps -u user4 -o pcpu,args | awk '$1>0'
```

see `man ps` for arguement of `-o` , some argument might be cputime,etime,args,comm,tty

Comment: hum despite I like the idea, the totla command returns nothing on my side, but when I only do `ps -u user4` I have the PID, TTY, TIME and CMD.

Comment: try adding XPG4= or UNIX95= before ps